# Find area of parallelogram given area sum of four segmented quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

Solution: Assume the parallelogram is a square with side length $s.$ Then by symmetry the four quadrilaterals are congruent. You can put the square on the coordinate plane and solve for the vertices of one quadrilateral, finding its area with shoelace. Multiplying this by four and setting that equal to 81, gives you $s.$ The area is $s^2.$

there's probably a much better way with area ratios/mass points/ceva Menelaus but idk.

I didn't understand her very well and I didn't like it very much either. Any other?

Comment: The given method is the best one, in my opinion. It works because affine transformation don't change the ratios of areas, and any quadrilateral can be turned into a square by an affine transformation. One could possibly find, however, a smarter way to compute the area of the four quadrilaterals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let [.] denote areas and $I=[AXZW]$ the area of the parallelogram. Then, one of the shaded quadrilateral areas can be evaluated from the areas of four triangles,

$$[CEGF] = [ACB]-[AED]-[AFB]+[AGD]\tag 1$$

For $[AGD]$, evaluate the ratio

$$\frac{[AGD]}{[AYD]}=\frac{AG}{AY}= \frac{[AXD]}{[AXYD]}
=\frac{[AXD]}{I - [XYZ] - [DYW]} = \frac{\frac16I}{I - \frac13I-\frac19I}=\frac3{10}$$

which leads to its area,

$$[AGD] = \frac3{10}[AYD] = \frac3{10}\cdot\frac1{18}I=\frac1{60}I$$

Follow the same evaluation steps to obtain the areas of the other three triangles

$$[ACB] =\frac4{39}I,\>\>\>\>\>[AED] = \frac1{33}I, \>\>\>\>\>[AFB] = \frac2{33}I$$

Plug the four triangle areas obtained into (1)

$$[CEGF] = \left(\frac4{39}-\frac1{33} -\frac2{33} +\frac1{60}\right)I=\frac{81}{2860}I$$

Then, from the given that the total shaded area is 81, i.e. $4[CEGF] = 81$, the area of the parallelogram is

$$I = \frac{2860\cdot81}{4\cdot81}=715$$